# How to make a command block output a negative signal

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im trying to make a wave spawn kind of thing and i would like a command block to activate its comparator redstone signal when the command blocks command is negative.

I tried this using /testfor @e[type=!Zombie] but that does not work as it detects the  player or any other mob. any way to do this without a redstone torch ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this is to have a second command block testing if the previous one failed:

[image: Chain command block leading off of an impulse command block]

The impulse command block would have your current command (`/testfor @e[type=Zombie]`).

The chain command block, which is the one you should run comparators/conditionals off of, would then have:

```
/testforblock X Y Z command_block -1 {SuccessCount:0}
```

`X Y Z` should be the coordinates of the impulse command block.

This makes the chain block succeed when the impulse block fails.

Comment: On some of the Command blocks i get the error "  ~ ~ ~ did not have the required NBT key if you know how to fix this. I cant find a tutorial for a fix on this on a command block. only chests and hoppers.

Comment: @CaolanMC That error means that the `testforblock` failed, ie: the command block the `testforblock` is targeting succeeded. The error does not indicate that anything is wrong with the system. Your coordinates should be pointing to the impulse block though, not to the chain block (`~ ~ ~`) that's running the `testforblock`.

Comment: im sure the coordinates are right. I dont see how i could have messed up hard enough to make a chain block try and detect itself.